# Can a partial view be rendered inside a MVC asp.net core view component?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have created a menu as a view component. One of the menu items is a login form and is rendered as a partial view inside the view component view. The form posts the user details to the account controller.

In the case where the user details are incorrect, I need to pass the model state error back to the view component ( from the account controller) which then needs to pass the error to the partial view.

So, my question is: what do I return from the account controller when user auth fails? I cant return a view or a partial view and I cant return a view component.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: a login form is kind of a separate concern from a menu, i would not combine them myself. if you want a well designed viewcomponent for menus and navigation you might like my project here: https://github.com/joeaudette/cloudscribe.Web.Navigation

Comment: Thank you - I will check it out.

Comment: @JoeAudette I had a look and it looks fine, but my question still remains. Any type of form ( not just logins) on a menu that is part of a view component will need to be able to be validated.

Comment: my opinion is that you run into this problem by mixing concerns that should not be mixed. login form could be linked from menu or it could be separate, it should not be part of the menu and the menu component should have no awareness of other concerns such as login logic

Comment: answer to the question of the title is yes, a partial view can be invoked from the view that is invoked by a viewcomponent. but such partial views should be limited to ones related to the menu not other concerns or other models involved

Comment: I do see your point - it was a bit of an experiment to see how much functionality could be put into a view component as its "sold" as a partial view on steroids but this particular instance seems to expose its limitations.